# Portfolio wordpress images dosen't show

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, portfolio

I'm making a website in wordpress and I download a pluggin "Visual Portfolio, Posts & Image Gallery" and the image dosen´t charge.

the image only appears in the preview, but in the final page donsn't appears, any idea why?

[image: This is the preview]
This is the preview

[image: and this is the final page]
and this is the final page

Comment: Try saving 'permalinks' again from Settings → Permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear your cache. --> "Clear Cache" in black header bar (and Browser Cache).

When you´re logged in as admin you´ll see an uncached version of your site.
When you browse your site as a visitor, you might see an old version because of the caching.